# SPFx webpart not working in IE11 - Reflect is undefined

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sharepoint-online, spfx

I created a custom form using SharePoint Framework and pure JS, HTML and Sass. No React, Angular or any other frameworks. The form works perfectly in Chrome but when I try displaying it on IE (which we have to support), I get the following error:

> Something went wrong
>   If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
>
> Technical Details
>   [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
>   ***Failed to load component "48a33395-b489-4696-b8ee-bcab3d186d5e"
>
> Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "48a33395-b489-4696-b8ee-bcab3d186d5e" (AgileHumanaIntakeFormWebPart). Original error: 'Reflect' is undefined

I am using PNPJS so I made sure to import their polyfill package at the top and I also tried installing and importing core-js with no luck.

```
import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11";
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

From what I can see in other similar issues, 'Reflect' is used in React but as I mentioned I'm not using React in my webpart so I'm at a loss.

I would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Reflect` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect#Browser_compatibility) by IE. It doesn't necessarily appear in react. You could also try to install and `import 'core-js/es6/reflect'`. Besides, have you enabled IE 11 mode? You need to enable IE 11 mode if you're using PnPJS. You could refer to [this link](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/ie11-mode/#configure-ie11-mode) to set the ie11 flag to true.

Comment: @YuZhou I have enabled IE11 mode for PnPJS. How do I specifically install that reflect module?

Comment: core-js version 3.x doesn't have separate folders for ES6 and ES7. Downgrade the core-js version to 2.5.7 will have separate ES6 and ES7 folders. As I have no idea how your project code and the error line look like, so I can only suggest you to give it a try.